# Docker-compose build: How to build an image for production and copy an app code to image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/

> Removing any volume bindings for application code, so that code stays
>   inside the container and can’t be changed from outside

I'd like to build image for production with my app code.

I have a file **docker-compose-prod.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:

    ------
    nginx:
        build:
            context: ./docker/nginx
        image: my_nginx:v1     
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./docker/app:/var/www/html
        depends_on:
            - php
   ------
```

The code of my app located in ./docker/app.
The Dockerfile located in ./docker/nginx and I can't with command COPY to copy an app code outside /docker/nginx folder.

When I run a build command I get an image without app contend in /var/www/html:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml build
```

How to build an image in this case with my an app code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the dockerfile in the build argument: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dockerfile

This way, I think that you can change your app context to be ./docker, and in the Dockerfile, copy the app folder to /var/www/html. This way, you no longer have to specify a volume when starting the app.

Answer (score 0):

Correct config looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:

    ------
    nginx:
        build:
            context: ./docker
            dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile-prod
        image: my_nginx:v1     
        ports:
            - 80:80
   ------
```

And the Dockerfile-prod in /docker/nginx

```
...   

COPY ./app /var/www/html

...
```